# How to dynamically call an imported namespace?

Tags: node.js, namespaces

I have 2 exporting files, which both export a function with the same name.

I can differentiate between the 2 since they'd be assigned to different namespaces. But I would like to call the namespaces dynamically without hardcoding the name into the code.

```
//exporter1.js
function boo(params)
{
    return 0;
}
module.exports.boo = boo;

//exporter2.js
function boo(params)
{
    return 1;
}
module.exports.boo = boo;

//mainarea.js
var exp1 = require('./exporter1.js');
var exp2 = require('./exporter2.js');

var ns = "exp1";

global[ns].boo(params); //This doesn't work
```

Comment: You could create your own object with "exp1" and "exp2" as keys and the respective modules as values, or if you don't need it to change in runtime simply dynamically require the module you want,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imported module is not stored in `global` variable. So you can't access it with `global`. You can do something like

```
//mainarea.js
var exp1 = require('./exporter1.js');
var exp2 = require('./exporter2.js');

var supportedModules = {
  'exp1': exp1,
  'exp2': exp2,
}

var ns = "exp1";

supportedModules[ns].boo(params);
```

Comment: It works. One step can be avoided, as well:

`const supportedModules = {
  'exp1': require('./exporter1.js'),
  'exp2': require('./exporter2.js');
}`

That said, I'm not sure if there's a performance impact in running things like this.